# How can I get the id of an unverified user on front-end?

Tags: craft3, users, activation, frontend-form

I would like to build a send activation email form on front-end, for users who didn't get or accidentaly delete the activation email.

I can call the `users/send-activation-email` action to achieve this, but this action only accept a `userId` as parameter, not the `email` address.

As I can't load unverified users from the front-end, it seems that I can't get the `id` of the current unverified user.

I know I could write a plugin for this, but I was wondering if there's any way to achieve this without?

Example of non-working send activation email form:

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    {{ csrfInput() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="users/send-activation-email">
    {{ redirectInput('') }}
    <input type="email" name="email" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the user by email

```
{% set user = craft.users.status(null).email("a@b.de").one() %}
{{ user.id?? 'no user found' }}
```